# Why do I get Run-time error '76' - Path not found - while running a code in VBA that works as intended?

Tags: vba

I get aforementioned Run-time error while running a code that actually works as intended. I want to create folders according to a list specified in column G and that works just fine.

```
Sub B_Ordner_erstellen_M2()

Dim rCell As Range

For Each rCell In Range("G:G")
MkDir rCell.Text
Next rCell

End Sub
```

Comment: What value is in Range("G:G")?  When you say "works as intended" do you mean it DOES create the directory you want?

Comment: it will error when you hit a blank cell. `For Each rCell In Range("G:G")` will try all 1.04 million cells.

Comment: Limit the range to the cells that could have the data and make sure the cell is not blank BEFORE trying to create a blank directory.

Comment: To Neil W: Yes it does create the folders

Comment: I would like it to ignore the blank cells then